# Exception CSRF check for routers node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf

I am using webook to call one of my routers in my node js application.
I want to not use 'csurf' which is a library for CSRF token when that specific router is called. 
The router is called `ch` and it is not the `index` router

My code for the CSRF expection is like this

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf();


var csrfExclusion = ['/check-ch'];
var conditionalCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
    if(csrfExclusion.indexOf(req.path) !== -1){
        next();
    } else {
        csrf(req, res, next);
        next();
    }
}
router.use(conditionalCSRF);

router.post('/check-ch',(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('i am here');
});
```

Normally I searched stackoverflow but all answer shows that the method above should work but in my `terminal` I end up getting invalid csrf token, and I am not sure why.

The CSRF token is also being used in the index.js router, by the same method, where I load it first and then directly use `router.use(csrfProtection)`, no `conditionalCSRF` is being used.

It looks like the conditionalCSRF is not even getting called, when I try to use a webook, so I am not sure what is stopping it to run.